# Filling time slots of employees on vacation (modifying Access DB)

Tags: mysql

Employee vacation schedule. When an employee takes vacation, I must make sure their job is filled (volunteers or drafted). 
Weekday employees work three eight hour shifts (per day), while weekend employees work two twelve hour shifts. While the open slots are posted and may be volunteered for, if not filled I must draft employees from other shifts to fill these open work slots. 
 Since weekend employees have to work sixteen hours of additional time before billing for overtime, I must first draft from that group.
 If I draft a weekday employee (for weekday slot), I can only have them work four hours. I must therefore draft two people to fill a full eight hour shift (two six hour slots for weekend openings). 
 The person drafted must have had a minimum ten hour break or come from the preceding shift (I cannot require a first shift employee to come in after eight hours off to fill the first half of third shift). 
The person with the least amount of year-to-date overtime is first on the draft list. 
I must be able to draft from groups (The person must be from a group qualified for the job they are being drafted to fill).

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding your database structure, I would first create a `view` to store the results of the business logic you have defined. For example, it would return the following:

- employee_id
- shift_type (weekend/weekday)
- hrs_since_last_shift
- overtime_this_year (order by this field, ascending)

Once that has been built, you can then query the `view` to perform a little filtering and determine who should be drafted for the shift.

```
SELECT *
FROM employeeView
WHERE hrs_since_last_shift > 8
AND shift_type = 'weekend'
... -- etc
```